# MvvmLightLibsStd10 and UWP

Tags: c#, data-binding, uwp, mvvm-light

How can you create a binding between a ViewModel and a View?

In the past there was a Locater created in App.xaml and then on the view you had this:

```
DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource ViewModelLLocator}}"
```

I can't even click in the Properties of the View and then create DataContext binding.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of MVVM light they changed how `ViewModelLocator` works due to it taking a dependency on `Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation` and the former not being .NET Standard compliant. It now should use `GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Ioc` to locate the `ViewModel` using `SimpleIoc`.

Here's an example how I used it in a recent UWP project.

In App.xaml

```
private ViewModels.ViewModelLocator Locator => Application.Current.Resources["Locator"] as ViewModels.ViewModelLocator;
```

In MainPage.xaml

```
DataContext="{Binding MainViewModel, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

In MainPage.cs

```
private MainViewModel ViewModel
{
    get { return DataContext as MainViewModel; }
}
```

In ViewModelLocator.cs

```
namespace YourNamespace.ViewModels
{
    public class ViewModelLocator
    {
        public ViewModelLocator()
        {                      
            Register<MainViewModel, MainPage>();            
        }

        public MainViewModel MainViewModel => SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();

        public void Register<VM, V>()
            where VM : class
        {
            SimpleIoc.Default.Register<VM>();

            NavigationService.Configure(typeof(VM).FullName, typeof(V));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found it out:

You need to add this in App.xaml:

```
private static ViewModelLocator _locator;
public static ViewModelLocator Locator => _locator ?? (_locator = new ViewModelLocator());
```

And then in the View.xaml:

```
this.DataContext = App.Locator.MainViewModel;
```

Comment: I don't know whats the best way? I will try your solution also.

Comment: If you've got it working, that's the right way.  There's more than one way to do it.

Comment: I'm using it the old way but I changed default ServciceLocator to Autofac